# TimerService EJB 3

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, timer

Related to TimerService, can I define two Timer instances and bind each timer to a specific (different) method annotated @Timeout in the same EJB?

Thanks,
Rod

Comment: Why would you want to do this? One timer can service many EJBs, can't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really.

However, you *can* define 2 timers

```
ctx.getTimerService().createTimer(1000, 1000, "timerA");
ctx.getTimerService().createTimer(1000, 1000, "timerB");
```

and have one timeout method to handle the timeout of both timers.

```
@Timeout
  public void handleTimeout(Timer timer) {
    String info = (String)timer.getInfo();
    if ( "timerA".equals(info) { handleTimerEventA(); }
    else if ( "timerB".equals(info) { handleTimerEventB(); }
}
```